# Trying to list data from an API is giving error message 'Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid:........'

Tags: react-native, graphql, expo, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Hey I am trying to display data from an API in a Flatlist but I keep getting the error message that says 'Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid:expected a string(for built-in components) or a class/function for composite components but got undefined....Check the render method of 'UsersScreen'

I am not sure what part of my code is causing this error

```
import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify'
import { Text, View, Flatlist } from 'react-native'


const listUsers = `query listUsers {
  listUsers {
      username


  }
}`;

class UsersScreen extends Component {

  listQuery = async () => {
    console.log('listing Users');
    const allUsers = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listUsers));
    alert(JSON.stringify(allUsers));
  };
 render() {
  return(
    <Flatlist 
    data={listUsers} 
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <View>
        <Text>{item.username}</Text>
      </View>
    )}
    />

  )
  }
}

export default UsersScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing  the import of Component:

```
  import { Component } from 'react';
```